# Can I use custom js function for FILTER cell function in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to use custom js function from the script as condition for FILTER cell function in Google Sheets.

Example: `=FILTER(A1:A25; colorsame(A1:A25; $A$10))`

`colorsame` returns `true`/`false` (one value or array, based on range size).

The custom function works well alone, like `=colorsame(A1:A25; $A$10)` fill the column. But in `=FILTER()` above I always have this error:

```
FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 25. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.
```

I've tried googling this problem, but only got solutions for `FILTER` based on built-in google sheets functions. Also I try to intergrate this function with Filter and Conditional Formatting "custom formula" field, but without success.

---

Custom functions code:

`color` returns the background color(s) of provided cell or range.

```
function color(input) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get 'input' address by metascanner
  var formula = ss.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.+)\)/).pop();

  var cell = ss.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = cell.getBackgrounds();
  return bg;
}
```

`colorsame` returns the truth table, which shows is the background color of the `input` range is the same as background color of `color` cell.

```
function colorsame(input, color) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get 'input' address by metascanner
  var formula = ss.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var matches = formula.match(/\((.+);(.+)\)/);
  var rangeA1Notation = matches[1];
  var colorA1Notation = matches[2].trim();

  var color = ss.getRange(colorA1Notation).getBackground();
  var bgs = ss.getRange(rangeA1Notation).getBackgrounds();
  var truthTable = bgs.map(function(bg) { return bg == color });
  return truthTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can return array of boolean values from custom function, which will indicate what cells will be shown after filtering.**

My problem was the try to parse cell content with regexp to retrieve cell address. It works for formulas like `=colorsame(A1:A25; $A$10)`, but not for using inside `FILTER`.

This version works, exclusively with `FILTER`:

```
function colorsame(input, color) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // get 'input' address by metascanner
  var formula = ss.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var matches = formula.match(/colorsame\((.+?);(.+?)\)/);

  var rangeA1Notation = matches[1].trim();
  var colorA1Notation = matches[2].trim();

  var color = ss.getRange(colorA1Notation).getBackground();
  var isSame = function(col) { return col === color; };

  var bgs = ss.getRange(rangeA1Notation).getBackgrounds();
  var truthTable = bgs.map(function(bg) { return bg.map(isSame); });

  return truthTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be useful to see the code of your `colorsame` function, but meanwhile, have you tried with

```
=ArrayFormula(FILTER(A1:A25; colorsame(A1:A25; $A$10)))
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Also tried `=FILTER(A1:A25; ArrayFormula(colorsame(A1:A25; $A$10)))`. Updated the post with code.